# composer doesn't find package if not using sudo command (root user)

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I came across this problem on ubuntu 22 operating system. the problem occurs with composer not finding the packages needed to install, but if I use sudo the packages are found and can be installed without problems.

example command to install laravel :
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen blog

error example
Could not find package laravel/lumen with stability stable.

I've solved this problem, but I forgot how. does anyone still remember? Please help me

Comment: Have you tried changing ownership of example-app folder ?

Comment: you have to check the composer permission in /usr/local/bin/composer. sudo chmod 755  /usr/local/bin/composer

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: is composer installed?

Comment: What is "this problem"? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam of course I have installed composer, and I have tried from local to global installation. but the same problem persists

Comment: @M.Ismail Of course I tried various methods including changing access permissions with, but the problem was not resolved

Comment: @NicoHaase composer cannot find lumen package. but if i use the sudo command the package installs successfully without any problem. but it's not good to use composer with sudo command

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Which version of Composer and PHP do you use?